# Does the adverb "fertig" always come with the preposition "mit"?

Tags: adverb

I am just starting to learn German, but I have come across the adverb "fertig" which means to finish, and I have noticed that it is always accompanied by the preposition "mit". Is that a rule in the German language or this is an exception in the piece which I am reading which is:

> Gerade als das kleine Schweinchen **mit** dem Hausbau **fertig** war und Blumen auf seinen schweren Holztisch stellte

Comment: "fertig" is no verb (see the heading of the question) and "fertig" does not mean "to finish".

Comment: Yes, German adjectives take idiomatic prepositions just like verbs do. Being done with something is expressed as *fertig* + *mit*. There's no particular reason why we don't habitually use e.g. *fertig* + *nach* instad, we just don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mit**+noun adds a topic, tool or companion to an adverbial phrase. These phrases don't translate into English very well:

> Ich bin einverstanden.

*I agree.*

> Ich bin **mit dem Preis** einverstanden.

*I agree on the price.*

> Wir waren unterwegs.

*We were travelling.*

> Wir waren **mit dem Rad** unterwegs.

*We were travelling by bike.*

> Ich war **mit meiner Frau** **mit dem Rad** unterwegs.

*I was travelling by bike, with my wife.*

Comment: Good answer. Are “subjects” of adverbial phrases always added with “mit”?

Comment: No. The meaning of adverbials depends on the preposition. *Ich bin einverstanden.* is an adverbial/predicative phrase, and *mit dem Preis* is another adverbial describing it. You may use other prepositions+nouns, adverbs etc. for other meanings.

Answer (score 5):

The form you saw is "mit etwas fertig sein", to be done with something. Hence the "mit", just like in English.

> Das Schweinchen war mit dem Hausbau fertig.
>
> The pig was done building the house.

In this case the English would be better translated without a noun, hence you wouldn't use "with". But consider this example:

> Das Schweinchen war mit der Arbeit fertig.
>
> The pig was done with its work.

Answer (score 3):

There plenty of uses for *fertig* that don't use *mit*. It can be used by itself or with other prepositions like *für*
.

> Das Haus ist fertig

Comment: Ich bin fertig (von der Arbeit). _I'm done_. Ich mach mich fertig für 's Kino. _I get ready for the cinema_. Ich mach ihn fertig. _I'll beat him._

Answer (score 1):

I would characterize "fertig" as a "transitive," rather than "intransitive," word for "done" or "finished."

In a "transitive" situation, one is done *with* something, call it X. Then, an appropriate sentence might be, "Ich bin fertig *mit* X."